# why adding a space after `(.+?)` can completely change the result

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to find a smaller string, `String patternString1 = "(John) (.+?)";`, within a larger string. The smaller string are consist of two groups i.e. `(John) (.+?)`. However, I have obtained completely different result just by adding a space after `(.+?)`.

for `String patternString1 = "(John) (.+?)";`, (i.e. without space), the result is

```
found: John w
found: John D
found: John W
```

For `String patternString1 = "(John) (.+?) ";`, (i.e. with space), the result is

```
found: John writes
found: John Doe
found: John Wayne
```

How come a space can make such a big difference to the result?

```
String text
        = "John writes about this, and John Doe writes about that,"
        + " and John Wayne writes about everything.";

String patternString1 = "(John) (.+?)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString1);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(1) + " " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.+?` quantifier is reluctant (or "lazy"). It means it will match the subpattern it quantifies *one or more times, **but** as few times as necessary to return a valid match*.

You have `(John) (.+?)` pattern and you try to find a match in `John writes about this`. The regex engine finds `John`, places it into Group 1 memory buffer, finds a space, matches it, and then finds `w` in `writes`. The `w` is matched, so the requirement of *one or more* is met. Since the match is already valid, it is returned. You get `John w`.

Now, you add a space after `(.+?)`. The `John` is matched and captured into Group 1 as before, the space is matched with the space in the pattern (again, as before), then `.+?` is executed - finds an empty location before `writes`. It matches this location and goes on to match a space. There is no space at that location, since there is `w`. The regex engine goes back to `.+?` and consumes `w`. Checks if `r` is a space - no, it is not. The engine checks the string this way up to the first matching space and finds it right after `writes`. Thus, your valid match for `(John) (.+?)`  is `John writes` .

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you include the trailing space, you are asking the pattern to match that space as well.

`John w` does not match anymore, because it does not end with a space.

It has to be expanded to `John writes` (note that the match includes the space at the end).