# Regexp with a delimiter ' -- ' without recursion

Tags: java, regex

So I have a string that can be either:

```
aa -- bb -- cc -- dd
```

or

```
aa -- bb -- cc -- dd -- ee
```

aa,bb,cc,dd,ee can be any character (except the delimiter which is ' -- ')

This is what I've tried:

```
(.*?) -- (.*?) -- (.*?) -- (.*)((.*?)|)
```

It almost works. It can capture the first but not the second one correctly.

I have to use capturing groups and capture strings between delimiters. Only matching is not enough.

So capture groups should be

aa
bb
cc
dd

OR

aa
bb
cc
dd
ee

Comment: How about `string.split("--")`?

Comment: Perhaps something like: `((.*?) -- ){3,4}(.*?)`

Comment: @VenomFangs [No Match](https://regex101.com/r/tZ3tC8/1)

Comment: Do you have to use capturing groups or do you only need to match the whole string? Are `-` and whitepace allowed chars in e.g. `aa`?

Comment: @Shafizadeh, try again, I had an extra space :)

Comment: Yes, I have to use capturing groups ! only matching is not enough.  - is allowed but whitespace not

Comment: If a space can appear in the fields, I suggest [`(.*?) -- (.*?) -- (.*?) -- (\S*(?:\s(?!--)\S*)*)(?: -- (.*))?`](https://regex101.com/r/gD9sQ4/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to go the regex way, I would use `^(\\S+) -- (\\S+) -- (\\S+) -- (\\S+)(?: -- (\\S*))?$`, capturing your content into 4 or 5 capturing groups.

I used the \S to avoid unnecessary expansion with the lazy matching, which will speed up the regex a bit. I also added anchors for start and end, as it seems you want to match a whole string.

Note: I'm not sure, how java handles capturing group repetition, in most regex flavours constructs like `(.){4}` will only capture the last repetition.

Comment: *backtracking with the lazy matching* - there is no backtracking with lazy matching. However, there is an overhead, yes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew for the incalid sample string `a b c d e f g` there will be backtracks for each space until it finally fails with e.g. `^(.*?) -- (.*?)` - if I don't understand it completely wrong. `^(\S+) -- (\S+)` however will fail, as soon as it hits `b`

Comment: See [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761836/why-adding-a-space-after-can-completely-change-the-result/35767048#35767048) of what a regex engine is doing with a lazy subpattern. There is no backtracking, just the subsequent patterns are retried if no match is found, the lazy subpattern "expands" on a no match if it can match more characters from the current position

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew as regex101 notes the expanding as backtracking (see e.g. https://regex101.com/r/zG1yG5/1 in the debugger) I mixed up terms - I have edited my answer to hopefully being more accurate

Answer (score 0):

Instead of capturing matches, just use your well-defined delimiter to `split` the string:

```
String text = "aa -- bb -- cc -- dd -- ee";
String[] parts = text.split("\\s*--\\s*"); // \s* to get rid of padding spaces
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output: `[aa, bb, cc, dd, ee]`

Alternatively, if you need the group information (e.g. the start position), you could just match agains the much simpler regex for a single group in a loop:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.+?)(?: -- |$)").matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("'" + m.group(1) + "'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following matches both, but you might want to make it more robust if you need it to be:

`((.*?) -- ){3,4}(.*?)`

Answer (score 0):

If I somehow had to use a single regex match and retrieve all the characters in groups, I would use one of the following :

```
([^ -]{2}).*([^ -]{2}).*([^ -]{2}).*([^ -]{2})(?:.*([^ -]{2}))?

(.{2}) -- (.{2}) -- (.{2}) -- (.{2})(?: -- (.{2}))?

(.*?) -- (.*?) -- (.*?) -- (.*?)(?: -- (.*?))?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
 -- |(..)
^--^------ notice the spaces
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZ5xD1/4)**

[image]

And in case you want multiple groups you could use:

```
(.*?) -- (.*?) -- (.*?) -- (\S*)(?: -- (.*))?
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZ5xD1/3)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make the last term *optional*:

```
(\S+) -- (\S+) -- (\S+) -- (\S+)(?: -- (\S+))?
```

I also changed to using `\S+` to avoid false positives for missing terms or badly formatted input.

Note also the use of a *non-capturing* group so the fifth (optional) term is in group 5 (instead of group 6).